# Яка етимологія слова "небога"

Tags: етимологія

Яка етимологія слова "небога"? СУМ-11 не розкриває походження слова.
[Етимологічний словник](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) не містить цього слова взагалі.

Чи є зв’язок між словом "небога" та "небіжчик" чи російським "убогая"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Небога* — донька брата або сестри, *племінниця*.

[«Етимологічний словник української мови» у 7 томах](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) (том 4) містить статтю *«небіж»*, яка повністю розкриває тему.

Коротко, етимологія походить від [ПСЛ](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) `nebogъ`, утвореного з частки `ne` «не» і основи іменника `bogъ` «доля, майно, багатство», буквальне значення «той, хто не має частки (при поділі майна)».

[image: Стаття небіж]
<sub>*(як завжди, перепрошую за скріншот зі словнику; нема у Мережі цього словника з розпізнаним текстом)*</sub>

> Чи є зв’язок між словом "небога" та "небіжчик" чи російським "убогая"?

Так, є, тому що йдеться про один і той самий [ПСЛ](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) корінь `bogъ` «власність, частка», але треба усвідомлювати, що такі слова досить древні, і тому будь-яка етимологія досить віддалена і не відтворює сучасних значень слів.

- *Небіжчик* — від [ПСЛ](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) прикметника `niebogi` «померлий, покійний», первісне значення — «той, хто вже більше не має своєї частки на цьому світі».
- *Убогий* — того ж походження, щось на зразок «віддалений від поділу частки майна».

Answer (score 10):

Зв’язок між словами «небіж» («небога») та «небіжчик» є — обидва походять від слова (чи принаймні спопіднені з ним) «[небогий](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/31964-neboghyj.html#show_point)» («бідний»), що має корінь «[-бог-](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/bog%D1%8A)» («-баг-»), який споріднює його зі словами «багатий» тощо.

Зв'язок між українським «небогий» і російським «убогий» теж є — «небогий» є первісним варіантом (принаймні так вважає Даль: «[встарь говорили небогий вместо убогий](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/279054)»).

Як у слів «[небіж](http://sum.in.ua/s/nebizh)»/«[небога](http://sum.in.ua/s/nebogha)» значення «племінник»/«племінниця» пов'язані зі (застарілим за СУМ-11) значенням «бідолашний»/«бідолашна» — загадка. [Отут](http://ru-etymology.livejournal.com/1283253.html) росіяни ламають над цим голову, але, здається, єдиного висновку не знайшли.

P.S.: Слово «небога» є в «Етимологічному словнику української мови» в семи томах, на який Ви посилаєтеся — просто воно розкривається в тій самій статті, що й «небіж».

P.P.S.: Від них же походить слово «[неборак](http://sum.in.ua/s/neborak)».